# My Codepen works well in desktop but not on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, flexbox

The layout becomes broken when viewed in phones. Here is the link to my codepen [Expanded Task Input](https://codepen.io/isletamj/pen/zYyqaqN). I used flexbox to layout this.

---

**Preview in Desktop**:
[Desktop Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Bns.png) |
[Desktop Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8mj5.png)

**Preview in Mobile**
[Mobile Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxVwG.jpg) |
[Mobile Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RThWs.jpg)

---

Here is the **HTML** part:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="input-frame">
      <div class="inputs">
        <input class="title-input" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
        <textarea class="description-input" name="description" rows="3" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
        <div class="date-input-container">
          Due date:
          <input id="date-input" name="date" type="date">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <div class="add-button">+</div>
        <div class="caret-up"><i class="caret-up-icon fa-solid fa-angle-up"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the **CSS** part:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.input-frame {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.caret-up {
  display: none;
  width: fit-content;
}

.caret-up-icon {
  transition: 100ms;
}

.caret-up-icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.add-button {
  background-color: #447e4d;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #d9d9d9;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
  transition: 200ms;
}

.add-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.title-input {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 7px 0 0 7px;
  padding: 0 12.5px;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.title-input:focus {
  /*   outline: 3px solid #447E4D; */
  outline: none;
}

.description-input {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12.5px;
  resize: vertical;
}

.date-input-container {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  transition: 200ms;
}

#date-input {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px 0 5px;
}

@keyframes descriptionEntry {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 80px;
  }
}
```

Here is the **JAVASCRIPT** part:

```js
const titleInput = document.querySelector(".title-input");
const inputFrame = document.querySelector(".input-frame");
const addButton = document.querySelector(".add-button");
const inputs = document.querySelector(".inputs");
const descriptionInput = document.querySelector(".description-input");
const dateInputContainer = document.querySelector(".date-input-container");
const dateInput = document.querySelector("#date-input");
const caretUp = document.querySelector(".caret-up");

titleInput.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  inputFrame.style.cssText = `
    padding: 5px;
    column-gap: 10px`;

  inputs.style.cssText = `
    flex: 1;
    row-gap: 5px`;

  descriptionInput.style.cssText = `
    display: block;
    animation: 500ms descriptionEntry forwards;`;

  addButton.style.borderRadius = "5px";

  titleInput.style.cssText = `
    padding: 15px 5px 0 5px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black`;

  dateInputContainer.style.cssText = `
    display: flex;`;

  caretUp.style.display = "block";
});

caretUp.addEventListener("click", () => {
  inputFrame.style.cssText = `
    padding: 0px;
    column-gap: 0px`;

  descriptionInput.style.cssText = `
    display: none;`;

  addButton.style.borderRadius = "0 5px 5px 0";

  titleInput.style.cssText = `
    border: none;
    padding: 0 12.5px;
    border: 7px 0 0 7px;`;

  dateInputContainer.style.cssText = `
    display: none;`;

  caretUp.style.display = "none";
});
```

---

I've tried testing it on a different phone and on a different browser on a mobile phone as well as on a different desktop and on a different browser on a desktop but still it only works well on desktops.

I've thought that maybe it is a codepen limitation but I've tried putting it on github pages and the problem is the same when viewed on phones so maybe it has something to do with my code and with the code compatibility on browsers

Comment: Could you turn your code samples into a code snippet?

Comment: I have tried in few mobile screen and seems its working. any particular screen resolution where you are facing issue??

Comment: @Leothelion I've tried it also on dev tools on desktop chrome and it looks ok but when I tried it on two phones - Poco X3 Pro and Samsung A12 - using chrome also  the layout looks like the image that I uploaded in preview in mobile

Comment: @isletamj checked in phone and found the issue. I can't check with more detail but try to give width:100% to .inputs class and update the code pan plz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Incorporating @Leothelion answer.

Changing the width in the .input-frame class to fit-content solves it

```css
.input-frame {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: fit-content;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: 7px;
  transition: 500ms;
}
```

it now looks the same as the desktop | [Demo](https://codepen.io/isletamj/pen/zYyqaqN)

I believe when you want to **contain elements inside a div** it is a good practice **to use fit-content** unless you have a specific width you want to achieve or when you are sure the width of the elements inside the div won't exceed the width of the parent div

*Don't know why is it like this and is different between desktop and mobile but if there is an expert here about how browsers renders it both in mobile and desktop feel free to share it tnx.*

Answer (score 0):

Please check here :

[Demo](https://codepen.io/avinafh/pen/VwqjXVZ)

you are missing width:

```
.inputs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:100%;
}
```

I have checked your code and found that you are using display:flex; that was creating gap between input box and button. If you will inspect your codepan then you will see.

I just added width:100% to remove that gap and wholia you are good to go. I will check article for more details (pin point) then i will update the answer for future use. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: You can click the edit button under your post to modify it. Also, its "CodePen" not "CodePan" (E not A)

Comment: @Greenreader9 nope some one cant add the link by simply edit. They have to type link with this tag [Codepen](link) so please if you want to help someone please do. Thank you.

Comment: @Leothelion Thank you. adding the width: 100% in the .inputs class made it look a lot better in mobile since it's already containing the different inputs inside. But upon further inspecting the codepen I found a **SOLUTION**: Just change the **width in the .input-frame class to width: fit-content** In this way it almost works the same as the desktop. I don't know why it creates this bug in mobile maybe it just renders content differently in mobile (not sure). But still thank you for pushing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ok no worries. If my answer helps you then accept as answer so in future people can check and get the answer/clue. Thank you